# Summing child objects rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, children

I have a model Task Orders that has_many Invoices. One of my Task Order attributes is "total invoiced". One of my Invoice attributes is "amount". I want a relationship where Total Invoiced = sum of "Amount". I want this to show up in my task_order/index page. Here is my task order index controller:

```
def index
 @task_orders = TaskOrder.all
 @invoices = @task_order.invoices
 @task_order.invoicedAmount = @task_order.invoices.sum(:amount)
end
```

I am getting the error undefined method `invoices' for nil:NilClass

I do want to mention that my code in task_order/show works:

```
def show
  @invoices = @task_order.invoices
  @task_order.invoicedAmount = @invoices.sum(:amount)
end
```

As a follow up question, I am much more familiar with SQL queries than I am using Active Record queries. Can someone point me to a guide on how to render the results of a pure SQL query?

Thank you!!

Comment: You realise you're not assigning `@task_order` in index? Shouldn't `invoiced_amount` be a method on `TaskOrder`? also, why are you not following Rails naming conventions? (`invoicedAmount`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `index` method is not going to work, because you're getting `@invoices` from `@task_order.invoices`, but you declare `@task_orders` instead. Note the singular vs. plural difference.

Comment: Hi @jken13579 - taking your comment into account, I modified my code to be:

  def index
    [at]task_orders = TaskOrder.all
    [at]invoices = [at]task_order.invoices

    [at]task_orders.each do |task_order|

      [at]task_order.invoicedAmount = [at]invoices.sum(:amount)

    end

  end

and I'm still getting the same error..

Comment: Your issue is because you're using `@task_order.invoices` and you're not declaring `@task_order`. Again, not the singular vs. plural. In addition, you should probably use `@invoices = Invoice.all`, because it seems like you want all invoices, and plus, `@task_orders.invoices`  will be invalid. You should really read through the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/).